# A world within our world, but hidden and doesn't look like Earth or affect it. Is it possible (or something close)?

Tags: magic, earth, teleportation

I'm new here and this is my first question.

I have a question which is a bit complicated about an idea that I like but that is confusing me at the moment. I appreciate if you bear with me and it would mean so much to receive your feedback.

I'm going to elaborate a bit about this question, so hopefully, you get a better idea. There is a world, inside our Earth, but it cannot be seen by humans - it is as if it isn't there for us. This inner world is both located and the same size as the inner part of our earth. At the same time, this hidden space is not affecting our earth in other ways (gravity, temperature etc.), because it only has the same space of our inner world, which is hidden. This earth is completely different than what our inner world looks like - it's like another world with different physical laws etc. Humans can access it through portals from above. Through these portals then they can be teleported into this 'other world' inside our world (Earth) - not by physically going there (i.e. drilling the earth or burrowing etc.) but through magic (portals). This world becomes real to us and starts effecting us only when it cracks through the surface if it expands; when it comes in contact with the surface of the earth (this is a very important aspect). This is like a world inside 'hollow earth', but with different geology (for example, there are no earth layers that we know of) and it exists like an invisible hidden space within our world that can be accessed by portals from above.

I know that it is a bit complicated because for me it seems that I have some kind of portal/parallel world hybrid in my mind. Maybe there is something else (a theory, a story, a question posted before this one that I haven't read, etc.) that is close to what I'm envisioning and that it can help me with world-building or researching similar ideas. Maybe it has been done! I'd like to add that I'm still in the early development of this world, if it can, after all, work.

I would appreciate if you let me know about anything you think might help me and would be very happy to answer your questions to clear some things up. Thank you for taking the time to read this and any feedback, criticism, thoughts etc. would be extremely appreciated!

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Worldbuilding Matt Matthews. Your idea sounds like a parallel universe/world or a magical universe/world. This is a pretty common theme and you can see it in books and movies such as Jumanji, Harry Potter, Artemis Fowl, Golden Compass, etc etc. The only issue is, I don't really see a question here. Stack Exchange is a question answer site. Which means we expect you to present us with an answerable question. Unfortunately the site is not setup for discussion, feedback or criticism and I would recommend an alternative site like reddit.com/r/worldbuilding if thats your aim

Comment: Hi @Shadowzee and thank you for the time you took to read my post and to write your comment. Much appreciated. I agree with you that it is similar to for example how the world of Harry Potter is existing in our world, but hidden. I guess that the only difference from my idea is that in HP the magical places are placed in abandoned human places, while what I'm trying to ask is how can I keep both places (our earth's actual layers and the magical world) existing in the same space? I apologise for posting this at the wrong forum and thank's a lot for directing me to the other link.

Comment: I would hardly say that the magical places in Harry Potter are abandoned. The Ministry of Magic is  directly under London (They accessed it via a telephone booth one time). Diagon Alley is placed behind a Pub. Gringots Bank is literally a huge underground cave, again in the middle of London. The Ministry of Magic for France in the Fantastic beast series is hidden in the middle of a busy walkway. And the Ministry of Magic for the USA is in a huge building just along the street. These magical places co-exist with the real world.

Comment: I agree with you. I used the wrong word when I used 'abandoned', because, as you rightly said, many aren't. What I should have said is an 'empty' space, like the many examples you kindly listed. Most are empty spaces that are filled with a hidden magical place (or objects) that cannot be seen by humans. For example a hidden building storey, etc. What I'm after is a magical place existing simultaneously in the same exact location of another human place - but we see one and the magical creatures see another. Sorry for not being clearer and thanks for commenting! Much appreciated.

Comment: If not an alternate universe, a possible solution is: They are made of energy and everything they create (structures, items..) is energy. (It might be some sort of dark energy/matter). Humans can't detect the energy and the energy can't interact with the physical world. Portals can be created with the same energy. The movie "[Midnight special](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2649554/)" has a related (but rather ambiguous) ending.

Answer (score 1):

**Such places are certainly possible!**

What you're describing are kinds of "hidden realms".  These are places created either by primordial forces and those who shaped them or else later my means of very high works of magic.

Some, rather like thaumically guarded places, allow for the interaction of ordinary Sun and weather while being invisible and inaccessible to all but those entrusted with the keys (a literary example might be Hogwarts); while others stand outside of ordinary time while remaining accessible (like Lothlorien).

Still others, as you hint, are hidden within the earth, accessible only via magical gates or portals.  Some occupy space within a planet, a sort of subterranean cavern (much like the Genesis Cave or the realms Thorinn visited while he was under ground); others of much greater magical potential occupy the same space and time as a portion of the planet while yet remaining distinct from it (Dante's Hell might be an example of this kind of hidden realm).

Comment: Hi @elemtilas and thank you so much for taking the time to read my question and for being so helpful. Much appreciated. The examples you mentioned are really helpful... I'm going to research those that I didn't know of. Thanks again for your answer!